# Remove LDR (TL116) toilet fill valve part under cap to flush

Tags: plumbing, toilet

[image]I'm trying to flush the top of the toilet fill valve. I've installed and it works great, levels correct, but after it stops flushing, the part under the cap leaks for a few minutes. I tried removing it like normal where you push down and turn counterclockwise, but it won't move. I took the cap off and pushed down and pulled up, won't move. I'm afraid of breaking it, so does anyone know "the easy way" to remove it? I couldn't find any info on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need to flush out the new valve. Sounds like the valve is not getting enough pressure from the float to shut off completely, until it gets a little more water in the tank. Try lowering the float so that the water shuts off half an inch lower than you have it currently set.

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott. I adjusted the bottom of the float and the silver pin and that seemed to work. If you notice in the picture, the clip on the silver pin is very high and it wasn't letting the grey lever rise to the top. With water coming all out of the top, I assumed there was debris.

Comment: Glad it was so simple. Please upvote and check off the answer so everyone knows your problem has been fixed!!